# Use Doctrine 2 ORM in Joomla 3.x when developing a custom component

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, custom-component, doctrine

I'm developing a component in Joomla 3 (I'm quite new to it). Because the database schema of the component is quite big, I think it's logical to use some ORM for DB abstraction, but I can't get up-to-date information for integrating Doctrine in Joomla.

The resources I've found:

- http://www.siimviikman.com/2010/03/01/building-joomla-component-with-doctrine-part-1/
- https://github.com/jooctrine/jooctrine

Since these are really old posts, I'm curious if anyone has tried in real world and if it is worth the effort.

Also: https://magazine.joomla.org/all-issues/issue-may-2011/using-doctrine-ORM-in-joomla

Comment: I think it is not worth the effort with latest Joomla 3.6, because with Joomla Core framework, JTable class, etc. Joomla supports a good framework itself. A good start for developing an extension in Joomla IMHO is https://www.component-creator.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Doctrine 2 ORM in several custom extensions and will update the Jooctrine repo; hopefully soon. Will publish about it then again too.

Our first goal however is to finish some custom, quite elaborate extensions; deadlines for delivery are nearing. We have changed a lot and developed some interesting things. So, keep an eye on the Jooctrine repo if you seriously want to work with Doctrine ORM in Joomla, but don't wait for it if you are in a hurry.

Comment: Any news to share on this front?